# How in Vue choose random name from from an array of names?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In "data" There is an array of Names: ['Bogdan', 'Ruslan' ...]. How to make a random name get selected from the Names array and inserted into the `<p> Names </ p>` tag?

I tried to do it like this --    `<p>{{Names[Math.floor(Math.random() * Names.length)]}}</p>` but for some reason it does not work

```
<f7-list
  media-list
  virtual-list
  :virtual-list-params="{ items, renderExternal, height: $theme.ios ? 63 : ($theme.md ? 73 : 46)}"
>
  <ul>
    <f7-list-item
      v-for="(item, index) in vlData.items"
      :key="index"
      media-item
      link="#"
      :title="item.title"
      :subtitle="item.subtitle"
      :style="`top: ${vlData.topPosition}px`"
    >
    <f7-block strong>
      <p>Name:{{Names[Math.floor(Math.random() * Names.length)]}}</p>
    </f7-block>
    <f7-block>
      <p>Surname:</p>
    </f7-block>
    </f7-list-item>
  </ul>
</f7-list>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
 Names: [ "Bogdan", "Vladimir", "Nikolay", "Stepan", "Sergey", "Igor", "Vladislav", "Miroslav", "Nikita", "Alexander", "Ivan", "Ruslan", "Maria", "Victoria", "Angella", "Zhanna", "Irina", "Marina", "Yulya", "Olya", "Dasha", "Natasha", "Masha"]
  const items = []
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1) {
    items.push({
      title: `UserID ${i}`,
      // subtitle: `SurName ${i}`,
    });
  }
  return {
    items,
    vlData: {
      items: [],
    },
  };
},
methods: {
  renderExternal(vl, vlData) {
    this.vlData = vlData;
  },
  randomName(){

  },
  loadMore(event, done) {
      window.location.reload();
  }
},
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning `Names` in your data object.

Try this

```
return {
  Names,
  items,
  vlData: {
    items: [],
   },
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing to much in the data section, instead use a function or a computed value to get your random name.

For example,

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.14/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>Name:{{ randomNameFunc() }}</p>
  <p>Name:{{ randomNameProp }}</p>
</div>

<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        Names: ["Bogdan", "Vladimir", "Nikolay", "Stepan", "Sergey", "Igor", "Vladislav", "Miroslav", "Nikita", "Alexander", "Ivan", "Ruslan", "Maria", "Victoria", "Angella", "Zhanna", "Irina", "Marina", "Yulya", "Olya", "Dasha", "Natasha", "Masha"]
      }
    },
    computed: {
      randomNameProp: function (){
        return this.Names[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.Names.length)]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      randomNameFunc() {
        return this.Names[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.Names.length)]
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I think that the computed property will return one value per component as Math.random is not reactive.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). For example:

```
  data() { 
    return {
      names: ['John', 'Carlos', 'Matt'] 
    }
  },
  computed: {
    randomName() {
      let n = this.names.length
      let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * n)
      return this.names[randomNumber]
    }
  }
```

You then can use

```
<p>{{ randomName }}</p>
```

Comment: The computed method will generate the same value on a single component. There is no reactive property in it so vue will cache the result. Each component will get a random value, but inside a single component, you'll get the same value no matter how many times you call the computed method. https://jsfiddle.net/yhs5aunx/

Comment: A computed property is reactive to data changes, for example if you do

  `mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.names.push("Phil")
    }, 5000)
  }`

the randomName prop is evaluated again.

Comment: A computed property is reactive to data change, but Math.random and Math.floor are not data changes. The only case when the computed property in your example will change is if names.lenth changes. There is no other property inside it that will trigger a computation. Try the jsfiddle and see that you'll always get the same 3 names.